# ES6: "Right" method of calling the static properties inside the class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

First, before this question will be downvoited, as you know in ES6 classes keyword `static` don't works for class properties. However, we can define it via get methods, as in the example below.

I learned that we can to call the static property inside the class by calling booth class name and `this`:

```
class Animation{

  static get SLOW (){ return 900; } // milliseconds
  static get FAST (){ return 300; } // milliseconds

  static getSlowSpeedValue(){
    console.log(this.SLOW); // works
    //console.log(Animation.SLOW); // works too
  }
}

Animation.getSlowSpeedValue();
```

Which method is technically right, which is the better practice?

By the way I also learned that we call any static methods inside the class by booth above ways:

```
class SomeClass{

   static method1(){
        SomeClass.method2(); // works
        //this.method2(); // works too
    }

    static method2(){
      console.log('OK');
    }
}

SomeClass.method1();
```

Comment: They're both "technically" correct, since they both work, but using `this` will have a higher mental burden (since it changes depending on the context), though it allows you to call that function with a different `this` value if you choose to use `.call`, `.apply` or `.bind`.

Comment: `Animation.SLOW` due to the way scope & prototype chaining.  This one is also faster, because doing `this` means it will check there first, if not found it will go to the prototype, by doing `Animation.SLOW`, you've skipped that bit and gone straight for the prototype.

Comment: @Keith, it's an answer, thank you! IMHO `this` for the static properties is not comfortable because in other PL `this` inside class is the instance calling, so the calling by class name as in Java PL is better. Do you agree?

Comment: @Keith: Uh? `this` and `Animation` refer to the same value. The property is defined on the function object itself, not on its prototype, so the prototype is never looked at.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, right never really looked at the `static` stuff in classes, for some reason assumed prototype.  But looking in Chrome  FAST and SLOW are attached to the `constructor` instance of the prototype, makes sense when you think about it.